# Проблема с QueryBuilder symfony (знак '?')

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, querybuilder

Проблема с QueryBuilder symfony (знак **'?'**)
`LIKE '%?amp=1%'` мне нужно это выполнить в запросе. Но QueryBuilder воспринимает **"?"** как символ подстановки. И подставляет параметр.

```
$qb
            ->select($this->stringQueryProvider->fetchDataSummaryAnnotationPage($annotationFilter, $pageSelect))
            ->setParameter('type', $this->getType())
            ->setParameter('projectUrl', $project->getGscaUrl())
            ->setParameter('startLast', $annotationFilter->getStartDate())
            ->setParameter('endLast', $annotationFilter->getEndDate())
            ->setParameter('startPrev', $annotationFilter->getStartDayPreviousPeriod())
            ->setParameter('endPrev', $annotationFilter->getEndDayPreviousPeriod());
```

То есть при попытке выполнить запрос я вижу вот это: `page_url LIKE '%'https://habi.co/'amp=1%'` ,где вместо **'?'** вставляется параметр `projectUrl`. Как можно объяснить QueryBuilderу что этот вопрос нужно считать как обыкновенный символ?

P.S. обратный слеш не помог. `addcslashes($conditionValue, '\\%_?')` тоже не помог.

сам запрос:

```
  SELECT  if(previousClicks == 0 and lastClicks != 0, 100, if(previousClicks == 0 and lastClicks == 0, 0, (diffClicks/previousClicks) * 100)) as percentClicks, sum(ifNull(lastClicks, 0)) as lastClicks, sum(ifNull(previousClicks, 0)) as previousClicks, (lastClicks-previousClicks) as diffClicks, if(previousImpressions == 0 and lastImpressions != 0, 100, if(previousImpressions == 0 and lastImpressions == 0, 0, (diffImpressions/previousImpressions) * 100)) as percentImpressions, sum(ifNull(lastImpressions, 0)) as lastImpressions, sum(ifNull(previousImpressions, 0)) as previousImpressions, (lastImpressions-previousImpressions) as diffImpressions, if(previousCtr == 0 and lastCtr != 0, 100, if(previousCtr == 0 and lastCtr == 0, 0, (diffCtr/previousCtr) * 100)) as percentCtr, if(lastImpressions == 0, 0, lastClicks/lastImpressions) as lastCtr, if(previousImpressions == 0, 0, previousClicks/previousImpressions) as previousCtr, (lastCtr-previousCtr) as diffCtr, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition != 0, 100, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition == 0, 0, (diffPosition/previousPosition) * 100)) as percentPosition, avg(ifNull(lastPosition, 0)) as lastPosition, avg(ifNull(previousPosition, 0)) as previousPosition, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition != 0, lastPosition, if(previousPosition != 0 and lastPosition == 0, -(previousPosition), (previousPosition-lastPosition))) as diffPosition FROM ( SELECT last.page_url,  sum(last.clicks) as lastClicks, sum(last.impressions) as lastImpressions, lastClicks/lastImpressions as lastCtr, avg(ifNull(last.position, 0)) as lastPosition from gsca_search_console_v2 as last where ( (last.project_url = :projectUrl) and (last.date >= :startLast) and (last.type = :type) and (last.date <= :endLast) and (sign > 0) and (page_url in (SELECT page_url FROM gsca_search_console_v2  WHERE (project_url = :projectUrl) AND (date >= :startPrev) AND (date <= :endLast) AND (type = :type) AND ( page_url LIKE '%/venta-apartamentos%' AND page_url LIKE '%?amp=1%' ) ))  ) group by page_url  ) lastStats full outer join ( SELECT previous.page_url,  sum(previous.clicks) as previousClicks, sum(previous.impressions) as previousImpressions, previousClicks/previousImpressions as previousCtr, avg(ifNull(previous.position, 0)) as previousPosition from gsca_search_console_v2 as previous where ( (previous.project_url = :projectUrl) and (previous.date >= :startPrev) and (previous.date <= :endPrev) and (previous.type = :type) and (sign > 0) and (page_url in (SELECT page_url FROM gsca_search_console_v2  WHERE (project_url = :projectUrl) AND (date >= :startPrev) AND (date <= :endLast) AND (type = :type) AND ( page_url LIKE '%/venta-apartamentos%' AND page_url LIKE '%?amp=1%' ) ))  ) group by page_url  ) previousStats USING page_url
```

Попробовал переделать через параметры:

```
SELECT if(previousClicks == 0 and lastClicks != 0, 100, if(previousClicks == 0 and lastClicks == 0, 0, (diffClicks/previousClicks) * 100)) as percentClicks, sum(ifNull(lastClicks, 0)) as lastClicks, sum(ifNull(previousClicks, 0)) as previousClicks, (lastClicks-previousClicks) as diffClicks, if(previousImpressions == 0 and lastImpressions != 0, 100, if(previousImpressions == 0 and lastImpressions == 0, 0, (diffImpressions/previousImpressions) * 100)) as percentImpressions, sum(ifNull(lastImpressions, 0)) as lastImpressions, sum(ifNull(previousImpressions, 0)) as previousImpressions, (lastImpressions-previousImpressions) as diffImpressions, if(previousCtr == 0 and lastCtr != 0, 100, if(previousCtr == 0 and lastCtr == 0, 0, (diffCtr/previousCtr) * 100)) as percentCtr, if(lastImpressions == 0, 0, lastClicks/lastImpressions) as lastCtr, if(previousImpressions == 0, 0, previousClicks/previousImpressions) as previousCtr, (lastCtr-previousCtr) as diffCtr, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition != 0, 100, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition == 0, 0, (diffPosition/previousPosition) * 100)) as percentPosition, avg(ifNull(lastPosition, 0)) as lastPosition, avg(ifNull(previousPosition, 0)) as previousPosition, if(previousPosition == 0 and lastPosition != 0, lastPosition, if(previousPosition != 0 and lastPosition == 0, -(previousPosition), (previousPosition-lastPosition))) as diffPosition FROM ( SELECT last.page_url, sum(last.clicks) as lastClicks, sum(last.impressions) as lastImpressions, lastClicks/lastImpressions as lastCtr, avg(ifNull(last.position, 0)) as lastPosition from gsca_search_console_v2 as last where ( (last.project_url = :projectUrl) and (last.date >= :startLast) and (last.type = :type) and (last.date <= :endLast) and (sign > 0) and (page_url in (SELECT DISTINCT page_url FROM gsca_search_console_v2 WHERE (project_url = :projectUrl) AND (date >= :startPrev) AND (date <= :endLast) AND (type = :type) AND ( page_url LIKE :conditionValueEscaped0 AND page_url LIKE :conditionValueEscaped1 ) )) ) group by page_url ) lastStats full outer join ( SELECT previous.page_url, sum(previous.clicks) as previousClicks, sum(previous.impressions) as previousImpressions, previousClicks/previousImpressions as previousCtr, avg(ifNull(previous.position, 0)) as previousPosition from gsca_search_console_v2 as previous where ( (previous.project_url = :projectUrl) and (previous.date >= :startPrev) and (previous.date <= :endPrev) and (previous.type = :type) and (sign > 0) and (page_url in (SELECT DISTINCT page_url FROM gsca_search_console_v2 WHERE (project_url = :projectUrl) AND (date >= :startPrev) AND (date <= :endLast) AND (type = :type) AND ( page_url LIKE :conditionValueEscaped0 AND page_url LIKE :conditionValueEscaped1 ) )) ) group by page_url ) previousStats USING page_url
```

Параметры:

```
array:8 [
  "type" => "page"
  "projectUrl" => "https://habi.co/"
  "startLast" => "2022-05-25"
  "endLast" => "2022-05-31"
  "startPrev" => "2022-05-18"
  "endPrev" => "2022-05-24"
  "conditionValueEscaped0" => "%/venta-apartamentos%"
  "conditionValueEscaped1" => "%?amp=1%"
]
```

Ошибка осталась...

Comment: А где сам текст запроса? Там же как-то должно быть так: `WHERE page_url LIKE ?` и в качестве соответствующего параметра `%?amp=%`

Comment: Добрый, обновил вопрос!

Comment: Надо значит все аргументы из LIKE также подставлять через `:param`, а не напрямую.

Comment: Сделал ошибка сохранилась

Comment: Оно по прежнему пытается вместо ? подставить параметр

Comment: Example - $qb->expr()->like('u.page_url', $qb->expr()->literal('%?amp=1%'))
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-0a267d5a2c69797a7656aae33fcc140d16b0a566-80

Answer (score 0):

Спокойно работает в Doctrine 2.6

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ags');
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->like('ags.loginApi', ':likeExpr')
);
$qb->setParameter('likeExpr', '?helloWorld');
```

Генерируемый SQL:

```
string(84) "SELECT ags FROM App\Entity\Test\TestAGS ags WHERE ags.loginApi LIKE :likeExpr"
```

Все параметры будут подставлены на моменте подготовки запроса и обработаны должным образом, после же, знак `?` не будет иметь никакого значения и интерпретируется как строка.